# twinkle configuration for Sangoma

Tags: voip, sip, asterisk, pbx, softphone

I'm able to run `AsteriskNOW` [virtualized](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405059/remote-virt-viewer-on-the-command-line) on my local system.  Also, I'm using Anveo on two different SIP hard phones.  Anveo works [fine](https://superuser.com/q/1216708/55747), indicating that the network handles SIP fine.

Now, how do I utilize the free [trial](https://support.sangoma.com/) from Sangoma SIP Station?

Because when I enter the credentials into twinkle:

`Failed to create a UDP socket (SIP) on port 5060
strerror_r is not available: 98`

```
thufir@dur:~/.twinkle$ 
thufir@dur:~/.twinkle$ cat freepbx.cfg 
# USER
user_name=<name>
user_domain=trunktrial1.freepbx.com
user_display=thufir
user_organization=
auth_realm=trunktrial1.freepbx.com
auth_name=
auth_pass=<password>
auth_aka_op=00000000000000000000000000000000
auth_aka_amf=0000

# SIP SERVER
outbound_proxy=
all_requests_to_proxy=no
registrar=
register_at_startup=yes
registration_time=3600
reg_add_qvalue=no
reg_qvalue=1

# RTP AUDIO
codecs=speex-wb,speex-nb,g711a,g711u,gsm
ptime=20
out_far_end_codec_pref=yes
in_far_end_codec_pref=yes
speex_nb_payload_type=97
speex_wb_payload_type=98
speex_uwb_payload_type=99
speex_bit_rate_type=cbr
speex_dtx=no
speex_penh=yes
speex_quality=6
speex_complexity=3
speex_dsp_vad=yes
speex_dsp_agc=yes
speex_dsp_aec=no
speex_dsp_nrd=yes
speex_dsp_agc_level=20
ilbc_payload_type=96
ilbc_mode=30
g726_16_payload_type=102
g726_24_payload_type=103
g726_32_payload_type=104
g726_40_payload_type=105
g726_packing=rfc3551
dtmf_transport=auto
dtmf_payload_type=101
dtmf_duration=100
dtmf_pause=40
dtmf_volume=10

# SIP PROTOCOL
hold_variant=rfc3264
check_max_forwards=no
allow_missing_contact_reg=yes
registration_time_in_contact=yes
compact_headers=no
encode_multi_values_as_list=yes
use_domain_in_contact=no
allow_sdp_change=no
allow_redirection=yes
ask_user_to_redirect=yes
max_redirections=5
ext_100rel=supported
ext_replaces=yes
referee_hold=no
referrer_hold=yes
allow_refer=yes
ask_user_to_refer=yes
auto_refresh_refer_sub=no
attended_refer_to_aor=no
allow_xfer_consult_inprog=no
send_p_preferred_id=no

# Transport/NAT
sip_transport=auto
sip_transport_udp_threshold=1300
nat_public_ip=
stun_server=
persistent_tcp=yes
enable_nat_keepalive=no

# TIMERS
timer_noanswer=30
timer_nat_keepalive=30
timer_tcp_ping=30

# ADDRESS FORMAT
display_useronly_phone=yes
numerical_user_is_phone=no
remove_special_phone_symbols=yes
special_phone_symbols=-()/.
use_tel_uri_for_phone=no

# RING TONES
ringtone_file=
ringback_file=

# SCRIPTS
script_incoming_call=
script_in_call_answered=
script_in_call_failed=
script_outgoing_call=
script_out_call_answered=
script_out_call_failed=
script_local_release=
script_remote_release=

# NUMBER CONVERSION

# SECURITY
zrtp_enabled=no
zrtp_goclear_warning=yes
zrtp_sdp=yes
zrtp_send_if_supported=no

# MWI
mwi_sollicited=no
mwi_user=
mwi_server=
mwi_via_proxy=no
mwi_subscription_time=3600
mwi_vm_address=

# INSTANT MESSAGE
im_max_sessions=10
im_send_iscomposing=yes

# PRESENCE
pres_subscription_time=3600
pres_publication_time=3600
pres_publish_startup=yes
thufir@dur:~/.twinkle$
```

just trying to configure twinkle with Sangoma trial.

Of course, works perfectly from CSipSimple using an Android tablet connected to the same network with wi-fi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Another program already bound to `5060`

While `strerror_r` was not available there, ostensibly to print error #98, [`strerror`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strerror.html)`(`**`98`**`)` here returns **`Address in Use`**.

I imagine the issue is that some other program (*e.g. AsteriskNOW*) is already listening on port `5060`, so *twinkle* would have to be configured to bind to a different port number.